# Google Docs, Enter a Date in one cell and have it autopopulate 6 months later

Tags: date, google-sheets, google-calendar-api, google-docs-api

I am currently tracking a commissions pay out. If I enter a date into one cell, can the next cell auto populate a date 6 months later? Using Google spreadsheet.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on [webapps.se]

Answer (score 1):

from: http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/1pRR0UkilZ8

The EDATE Function is perfect for this! It adds (or subtracts!) a number-of-months from a date

=EDATE(start_date, months)

So, your example would look like

=EDATE(date_completed, 6)

=if(C2="";"";EDATE(date_completed, 6))

Comment: Fantastic, Works like a charm.  The second cell is auto generating a random date till I input a date in the original cell. Is there a way to have it blank until data is added. If not no big deal.

Comment: see:  http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/rY3dReJCQ68